# Cross domain image in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have an app on app.domain.com and I want to load some images as textures from image1.domain.com, image2.domain.com, etc.

I am using  this code:

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
image.onload = function() {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
};
image.src = url;
```

On my image response header I have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:app.domain.com` but I still get this error

> three.js?201606101337:30942 DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at url may not be loaded.

Comment: I guess you meant "image **response** header".

Comment: yes, on the response header

Comment: Changed that for you in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [Texture Loader](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader)? It probably handles some edge cases:

```
var loader=new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");
loader.load(
  url,
  function do_something_with_texture(tex) { }
);
```

If that doesn't work, try changin the header to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Also, be aware that CORS does not work well in Safari (OSX, iOS browser and webviews).

Comment: Post the image url please, I'll check if the headers are right.

Comment: Ok so the problem was that i needed some cookies, so setting
    image.crossOrigin = 'use-credentials';
did the trick

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.setCrossOrigin("");
var map = textureLoader.load("image.png");
```